# Rally 2.0 JavaScript API - Creating HTML tables and setting values dynamically

Tags: rally

I'm using Custom HTML Rally Grid to develop a table that must return some statistics. My JavaScript is being called at the head of my HTML and i'm creating a table in the body tag. So, my JavaScript is setting values in the table using the fields ids. The problem is: the table is being loaded but when the Rally.launchApp method runs, the table disappears. Curiously, if i check the font-code, the table still there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Grid With Freeform Data Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0rc1/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function() {
            Ext.define('CustomApp', {
                extend: 'Rally.app.App',
                componentCls: 'app',

                launch: function() {
                    var firstMetricResult;
                    var secondMetricResult;
                    var firstMetricName = "% of user stories assigned story points";
                    var secondMetricName = "Average story points per user story ";

                    var currentProjectName =  Rally.environment.getContext().getProject().Name;
                    var currentProjectNameID = document.getElementById("currentProjectNameID");
                    currentProjectNameID.value = currentProjectName;

                    var benchmark = 20;

                    var storiesQuery = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                        model: 'UserStory',
                        fetch: ['PlanEstimate', 'LastUpdateDate'],
                        filters: [
                                    {property: 'ScheduleState',
                                     operator: '=',
                                     value: 'Accepted'}, 
                                    {property: 'DirectChildrenCount',
                                     operator: '=',
                                     value: '0'},
                                    {property: 'AcceptedDate',
                                     operator: '<',
                                     value: 'LastMonth'},
                                    {property: "Iteration.Name",
                                     operator: "!contains",
                                     value: "hardening"},
                                    {property: "Iteration.Name",
                                     operator: "!contains",
                                     value: "regression"},
                                    {property: "Iteration.Name",
                                     operator: "!contains",
                                     value: "stabilization"}
                                  ]
                    });

                    storiesQuery.load({
                        callback: function(records, operation) {
                            if(operation.wasSuccessful()) {
                                var estimatedStoriesCount = 0;

                                Ext.Array.each(records, function(record){
                                    if (record.get('PlanEstimate') != null){
                                      estimatedStoriesCount++;
                                    }
                                });

                              var storiesCount = records.length;
                              firstMetricResult = (estimatedStoriesCount*100)/storiesCount;
                              alert(firstMetricResult);
                            }
                        }
                    });


                    var estimatedStoriesQuery = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                       model: 'UserStory',
                       fetch: ['PlanEstimate', 'LastUpdateDate'],
                       filters: [
                           {property: 'PlanEstimate',
                            operator: '!=',
                            value: 'null'},
                           {property: 'ScheduleState',
                            operator: '=',
                            value: 'Accepted'}, 
                           {property: 'DirectChildrenCount',
                            operator: '=',
                            value: '0'},
                           {property: 'AcceptedDate',
                            operator: '<',
                            value: 'LastMonth'}
                        ]
                    });

                    estimatedStoriesQuery.load({
                        callback: function(records, operation) {

                            if(operation.wasSuccessful()) {
                              var astoriesCount = records.length;
                              var storiesPointsSum = 0;

                              Ext.Array.each(records, function(record){
                                  storiesPointsSum += record.get('PlanEstimate');
                              });

                              secondMetricResult = storiesPointsSum/astoriesCount; 
                              alert(secondMetricResult);

                            }
                        }
                    });

                }   
            });

            Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                name: 'Grid With Freeform Data Example'
            });

        });
    </script> 

    <style type="text/css">
        table.gridtable {
            font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
            font-size:11px;
            color:#333333;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-color: #666666;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        table.gridtable th {
            border-width: 1px;
            padding: 8px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #666666;
            background-color: #dedede;
        }
        table.gridtable td {
            border-width: 1px;
            padding: 8px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #666666;
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>


  <table border=1 class='gridtable' id="tab1">

  <tr>
  <th> Team </th>
  <td><b>All prior periods</b></td>
  <td><b>All prior periods</b></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td id="currentProjectNameID">
  </td>

  </tr></table>



</body>
</html>
```

I decided to use this simple HTML table because i want to have the power to edit the CSS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answer is correct.  Generally when working with apps (and ExtJS) most content is created through javascript rather than literally declared dom.

Check out this guide for a little more info on working with content in apps: https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/guide/add_content

Something like this should work though if you're still sold on the manual dom manipulation:

```
launch: function() {
    this.add({
        xtype: 'component',
        html: [
            '<table border=1 class="gridtable" id="tab1">',
            '<tr>',
            '<th> Team </th>',
            '<td><b>All prior periods</b></td>',
            '<td><b>All prior periods</b></td>',
            '</tr>',
            '<tr>',
            '<td id="currentProjectNameID"></td>',
            '</tr>',
            '</table>'
        ].join('')
    });
},

afterRender: function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);

    //the rest of your code that used to be in launch here
}
```

Then you should be able to look up the elements by id and manipulate them as you'd like.

Comment: Is there a way to do it as i'm trying?

Comment: I updated the answer with an example.  Does that work for you?

Comment: Ah, yes.  It's because the content is still not rendered at that point.  You'll have to wait to do anything that uses the dom until at least afterRender.  I updated the code above and it should work for you now...

Answer (score 1):

You would still be able to modify the CSS if you used an Ext grid or a rallygrid - besides using normal CSS selectors to style the grid, you also have access to certain properties when creating the grid - the renderer function for a column takes meta as its second parameter, which has an attribute called tdCls which you can use to style cells in that column.  For example:

```
.green > .x-grid-cell-inner {
    border     : 1px solid #afd3b6;
    background : #c6efce;
    background : -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #c6efce 0%, #afd3b6 100%);
    background : -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#c6efce), color-stop(100%,#afd3b6));
    background : -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #c6efce 0%,#afd3b6 100%);
    background : -o-linear-gradient(top,  #c6efce 0%,#afd3b6 100%);
    background : -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #c6efce 0%,#afd3b6 100%);
    background : linear-gradient(to bottom,  #c6efce 0%,#afd3b6 100%);
    filter     : progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c6efce', endColorstr='#afd3b6',GradientType=0 );
}

{
     text      : 'State',
     dataIndex : 'c_WINListState',
     editor    : 'stateeditor',
     renderer  : function(value, meta, record) {
         if (value === 'At Risk') {
              meta.tdCls = 'yellow';
         } else if (value === 'Off Track') {
              meta.tdCls = 'red';
         } else if (value === 'On Track') {
              meta.tdCls = 'green';
         } else if (value === 'Complete') {
              meta.tdCls = 'grey';
         }
         return value;
     }
 },
```

I would recommend using the built in functionality.

That being said, I think this is the reason for the built in functionality - if you look at the SDK, the launch app function states:

*Create and execute the specified app. Ensures all required components have been loaded and the DOM is ready before app code begins executing. As soon as all required dependencies have been loaded the launch method will be called.*